# Multidimensional Dynamic Memory Vector c++

Tags: c++, vector, dynamic-memory-allocation

I do this program in c++. 
I want to build a table with random rows and 3 columns. When I compile there is no mistake but I execute the program do nothing and write nothing. Can you help me to find my error?

Thanks

```
int main(){
srand(time(0));
int project = (rand() % 5) + 1 ;   
std::cout << "The Number is " << project << "." << std::endl;

vector<vector<int> > P(project, vector<int>(3));

for(int i = 0; i <= P.size(); ++i){
  for(int j = 0;j <= P[i].size();++j){
        P[i][j] = (rand() % 50)+10;
        P[i][j] = (rand() % 2)+1;
        P[i][j] = (rand() % 50)+1;
  }
 }

 for(int a = 0;a <= P.size();++a){           
  for(int j = 0;j <= P[a].size();++j){
      std::cout << "Project "<< a <<" :"<< P[a][j] ;
        std::cout << P[a][j] <<" , ";
        std::cout << P[a][j] <<" ."<< std::endl;  
 }
 }
```

I get another problem it writes the same value for all the columns. So I need to change something in my loop right?

Comment: What happens when you step through your program in the debugger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues, you should be using `size_t` for the loops instead of `int` and you were going over by one in the loops. For example it should be `i < P.size()` instead of `i <= P.size()`:

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < P.size(); ++i)
{
  for(size_t j = 0;j < P[i].size();++j)
  {
    P[i][j] = (rand() % 50)+10;
    P[i][j] = (rand() % 2)+1;
    P[i][j] = (rand() % 50)+1;
  }
 }
```

Also, did you mean to write to the same entry, three times, what was the purpose of that? Also, you output the same entry three times as well. I modified to only output once:

```
for(size_t a = 0;a < P.size();++a)
{           
 for(size_t j = 0;j < P[a].size();++j)
 {
   std::cout << "Project "<< a <<" :"<< P[a][j] << std::endl;  
 }
}
```

Also if you are have `using namespace std` in your code I would advise against it. Just use `std::vector` explicitly.

Comment: this is not very important in most cases but maybe you would like to also note that one should use MAX_RANGE to ensure that your random numbers are uniformly distributed, now you have slightly skewed distribution

Comment: thanks now something appears. But i have the problem that it write all the time 3 times the same thing like 000111222...

Comment: size_t is just a typedef int(unsigned)

Comment: @user2152947 I amended my answer to address that issue, I was a little confused about what you intended.

Comment: @GeraldSv see previous thread http://stackoverflow.com/a/1114031/1708801

Comment: I can't find how to write different things in each columns. is it possible?